# How to create catalog in indexing service using c#

Tags: c#, windows, service, indexing

I want to automate Windows Indexing Service.

This has to be done in c#.

Concept is :- 
I have a folder.
Client uploads docs in that folder
Client will search docs using Window Indexing Service.

Above steps are there in application.

I am making an installer and want to automate window indexing service on client machine.

Please help!! Any ideas are welcome.
I have been googling, didn't found solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Windows Indexing, but these look like promising places to start:

- [MSDN: Querying the Index
  Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266517%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [MSDN: Windows Search Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965362%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Searching Indexing Service](http://www.winnershtriangle.com/w/Products.IndexServerCompanion.SampleSearch.ASPNetCSharpSRC.html)
- [Using the Windows Indexing
  Service](http://www.winnershtriangle.com/w/CSharpHelp_WindowsIndexingService.asp)